# Doctrine 2 - Sort method for EntityRepository?

Tags: doctrine-orm

Is there a way to sort a Doctrine 2 `EntityRepository` Object with specific criteria or do I have to use a DQL query if I want to pass specific sorting parameters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can return an ordered set of elements by passing a second argument into the find___ methods, this argument must be an associative array where the key is the name of the field you want to order and the value is either 'ASC' or 'DESC'.

```
// query for one product matching be name and price
$product = $repository->findOneBy(array('name' => 'foo', 'price' => 19.99));

// query for all products matching the name, ordered by price
$product = $repository->findBy(
    array('name' => 'foo'),
    array('price' => 'ASC')
);
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#fetching-objects-from-the-database

Of course, if you want a most sophisticated behavior you should implement a custom repository.

Comment: Thanks that's just the thing I'm looking for!